# Replace inner html in javascript

Tags: javascript, replace, innerhtml

The following should replace all urls with their shortened version:

```
shareSection.innerHTML = shareSection.innerHTML.replace(expanded, shortened);
```

The html looks like this:

```
<section id="share">   
    <ul class="share">
        <li><label>Share:<input type="text" value="http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/" readonly /></label></li>
        <li><label>Embed:<input type="text" value="<iframe src=&quot;http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/&quot;></iframe>" readonly /></label>
    </ul>
    <ul class="share">
        <li><a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/&t=Is%20this%20site%20great%C3%9F" target="_blank" title="Share on Facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on Facebook</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?&url=http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/&text=Is%20this%20site%20great%C3%9F" target="_blank" title="Tweet"><i class="fa fa-twitter-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Tweet</span></a></li>
        <li><a href="https://plus.google.com/share?url=http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/" target="_blank" title="Share on Google+"><i class="fa fa-google-plus-square fa-2x" aria-hidden="true"></i><span class="sr-only">Share on Google+</span></a></li>
    </ul>    
    <input type="button" id="shorten" value="Shorten links" />
</section>
```

But for some reason it only replaces:

```
<li><label>Share:<input type="text" value="http://easypolls.herokuapp.com/1/" readonly /></label></li>
```

How could this be done?

Comment: Use a global flag?

Comment: Try this: `const regex = new RegExp(expanded, "g");
shareSection.innerHTML = shareSection.innerHTML.replace(regex, shortened);`

Comment: What are the values of `epanded` and `shortened`? Are they a regular expression and a function respectively? I would be looking at using a [string replacement function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_function_as_a_parameter).